# How to set MovieClip position without messing up tween?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, box2d

I'm working on a AS3 and Box2D game with moving platforms. The platforms are animated in Flash, and in actionscript I can read in their current position and adjust the physics bodies to match.

However, there's always a delay, where the animation is one frame ahead of the physics. I wanted to fix this by reading in the clip's current position, storing it for later, and then putting the clip back to its position at the last frame.

But when I do this, it systematically refuses to budge.

I coded up a simple test with a single moving box to test the idea, and I get the same problem ("movingBox" is a symbol that animates a single "box" symbol within it):

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            m_movingBox = new MovingBoxClass();
            addChild(m_movingBox);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }

        private function onEnterFrame(i_event:Event) : void
        {
            const box : Sprite = m_movingBox.getChildAt(0) as Sprite;
            trace("frame:", m_movingBox.currentFrame, ", x:", box.x);

            box.x = 0;
        }


        [Embed(source="../lib.swf", symbol="movingBox")]
        private var MovingBoxClass:Class;

        private var m_movingBox : MovieClip;
    }

}
```

Instead of printing out the positions of the moving box, the box just stays still, and the trace call outputs:

```
frame: 1 , x: 0
frame: 2 , x: 0
frame: 3 , x: 0
frame: 4 , x: 0
frame: 5 , x: 0
...
```

Any ideas? Thanks

**UPDATE:** Just to be clear, if i remove the `box.x = 0;` line, the box moves correctly and the trace call spits out increasing values for x.

**UPDATE:** I put up the examples:

[The output](http://heavenstone.net/tmp/test.swf)

[The lib, with "movingBox" on the stage](http://heavenstone.net/tmp/lib.swf)

[The Flash file](http://heavenstone.net/tmp/lib.fla)

[Zip file containing the Flash Develop project and all the rest](http://heavenstone.net/tmp/testClip.zip)

Answer (score 0):

**upd:**

```
package{    
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;    
public class Main extends Sprite {

    public function Main():void {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        // entry point            
        m_movingBox = new MovingBoxClass();
        this.addChild(m_movingBox);
        m_movingBox.stop();
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    }

    private function onEnterFrame(i_event:Event) : void    {
        var str: String = m_movingBox.getChildAt(0).x + ' - ';
        m_movingBox.gotoAndStop(m_movingBox.currentFrame + 1 < m_movingBox.totalFrames ? m_movingBox.currentFrame + 1 : 0);
        str += m_movingBox.getChildAt(0).x;
        trace(str);
    }        

    [Embed(source="../lib.swf", symbol="movingBox")]
    private var MovingBoxClass:Class;        
    private var m_movingBox : MovieClip;
    }    
 }
```

now you can manage this animation and adjust other coords every frame

Comment: Yeah, `m_movingBox` doesn't move itself, only `box` moves, under the influence of a tween in `m_movingBox`

Comment: @ drpepper - so `m_movingBox` stands still carrying `box` and managing it's animation? may i somehow take a look? and a stupid question: are you sure that you're tracing the correct child? did you try to change it's `alpha` for example? btw your problem can be caused by the fact that some tweeners use timers instead of enter_frame

Comment: @www0z0k I put up the examples above. I'm not using any custom tweening code or anything, this is just straight "motion tween" in the flash editor.

Comment: @ drpepper - test.swf shows a rectangle standing still. downloaded the files... i use flash cs4, could you make a compatible .fla?

Comment: @www0z0k No problem, I just replaced lib.fla with the CS4 version. I export this to lib.swf (which still moves, as you can see). Its when I import it in my program (test.swf) that I prevent it from moving with the `box.x = 0` line. Its normal that it's not moving. But, what I can't get is why I can't read in it's tween position in my trace call. Shouldn't it have been moved already by its animation?

Comment: @ drpepper - maybe you're tracing some nested sprite? i'll take a look)

Comment: @ drpepper - looks like i need a source fla for test.swf. i think it'll be possible to manage animation with `gotoAndPlay()` and `gotoAndStop()`

Comment: @www0z0k I compile test.swf with just a single AS3 file in it, using flash develop. Here, I'll add a zip file that contains the project along with all the rest, if that's easier.

Comment: @ drpepper - updated my answer. it has 60 frames of animation so you can manage position with `gotoAndStop()`. btw if i set `box.getChildAt(0).alpha = 0` i get just the white screen

Comment: @www0z0k allright, but what i'd like to do is read in the position that the animation should have put it at, and then change that position. in the example i gave that's stupid of course, becuase i always set the position to zero. but what i'd like to do is delay the animation by one frame. 

something like:
`newX = box.x;
box.x = lastX;
lastX = newX; `

do you see what i mean?

Comment: @www0z0k Thanks a lot for your help, but unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for. I need to be able to "read in" the position on one frame, while I reset the position to something else. It seems I can't do both simultaneously.

Comment: @ drpepper - you can make a trick: store the position for every frame (looping programmatically through them in the frame when it's loaded) and then apply known corrections